# Ruby method variable declaration

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I'm trying to define methods to parse through an apache log file and pull ip addresses, URLs, requests per hour, and error codes.  I've got everything working outside of methods, but when attempting to put that code into the methods I keep getting the error message "Stack level too deep."  Here is the code in question.

```
   class CommonLog

    def initialize(logfile)
        @logfile = logfile
    end

    def readfile
         @readfile = File.readlines(@logfile).map { |line|
    line.split()
  }
  @readfile = @readfile.to_s.split(" ")
    end

    def ip_histogram
        @ip_count = 0
        @readfile.each_index { |index|
            if (@readfile[index] =~ /\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/ )
                puts @readfile[index]
                puts @ip_count += 1
            end
        }
    end

    def url_histogram
        url_count = 0 
        cleaned_file.each_index { |index|
            if (cleaned_file[index] =~ /\/{1}(([a-z]{4,})|(\~{1}))\:{0}\S+/ )
                puts cleaned_file[index]
                puts url_count += 1
            end
        }
    end

    def requests_per_hour
    end

    def sorted_list
    end

end

my_file = CommonLog.new("test_log")
cleaned_file = my_file.readfile
puts cleaned_file.ip_histogram
```

Comment: Your code is too long, your explanation insufficient. What do you mean by "methods"? Are you referring to HTTP methods, or Ruby methods? Which part of the code is it? Can you trim down your code so that only the relevant code remains? Also, can you include two-three sample rows from your input file so we can test your code ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem lies on you `CommonLog#readfile` method:

```
def readfile
  @readfile = File.readlines(@logfile).map { |line|
    line.split()
  }
  @readfile = readfile.to_s.split(" ")
end
```

Notice that inside the implementation of `readfile` your calling `readfile` recursively? When it executes it reads the lines from the file, maps them and assign the result the `@readfile`; then it calls `readfile` and the method starts to execute again; this goes on forever, until you stack blows up because of too many recursive method calls.

I assume what you actually meant is:

```
@readfile = @readfile.to_s.split(" ")
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem, but now I'm having a new error undefined method 'ip_histogram' for #<Array:0x2de048> (NoMethodError)

I've updated the code in the original question.